# result database names and use them dynamically query

Tags: database

my query

```
SET @hastane=4;
```

since the data is sent by the system it can change so I use variables

```
SET @mp=(SELECT CONCAT('mediportal',IF(CHAR_LENGTH(@hastane)>1,CONCAT('_',@hastane),CONCAT('_0',@hastane))));
```

where the length of the incoming data is greater than 1 decimal

```
SET @sorgu1=("SELECT
tt.vt
FROM
(SELECT
IF(t.TABLE_SCHEMA=@mp,@mp,'mediportal') as vt,
IF(t.TABLE_SCHEMA=@mp,1,0) as deger
FROM
information_schema.`TABLES` t
WHERE t.TABLE_SCHEMA like 'mediportal%'
GROUP BY t.TABLE_SCHEMA)tt WHERE tt.deger=1");
```

I will check if the relevant database is there after the above operations are finished. `@sorgu1` result mydatabase name

```
PREPARE deneme from @sorgu1;
EXECUTE deneme;
```

My question;

How can I use the result from `@sorgu1`

example `SELECT * FROM @sorgu1.tables_name`
or how can i use `@sorgu1(database name)` in query

Comment: You should maybe format your question properly so it is easier to read. No one likes to decipher hyroglyphics when trying to help.

Comment: so sorry my mistake